# React / TypeError: files.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, file, input, state

I am trying to upload some files via `<input type="file">` to the state, in order to pass it back to the main component. With the code below I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` when trying to update the state with the uploaded files.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as RB from 'react-bootstrap'

import Button from 'components/Button/Button'

class uploadMob extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            files: [],
        }
    }

    onFilesAdded(files) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            files: prevState.files.concat(files),
        }))
        this.handleUpload()
    }

    handleUpload = (e) => {
        const { pdfUploadToState } = this.props

        debugger
        pdfUploadToState(this.state.files)
        console.log('PUSHED FILE', this.state.files)
    }

    render() {
        const files = this.state.files
        return (
            <RB.Form.Group>
                <div className="upload-btn-wrapper">
                    <div className="Files">
                        {files.map((file, key) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={key} className="Row">
                                    <span className="Filename">
                                        {file.value}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <Button size="sm" variant="light">
                        Dateien hochladen
                    </Button>

                    <input
                        type="file"
                        name="file"
                        id="files"
                        onChange={this.onFilesAdded}
                    />
                </div>
            </RB.Form.Group>
        )
    }
}

export default uploadMob
```

I would very much appreciate the help with this. It is driving me a bit crazy..

Comment: transform onFilesAdded to arrow function, it has problem now to find "this" of setState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
onFilesAdded(files) {
```

You need to either [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it to `this` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        files: [],
    };

    this.onFilesAdded = this.onFilesAdded.bind(this);
}
```

or convert it to an arrow function:

```
onFilesAdded = files => {
```

The problem is `this` referred inside `onFilesAdded` does not point the component instance by default. By using the two methods above, we make sure that by calling `this.`, the component is correctly referred.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an arrow function to have the correct value of `this`.

`setState` is **asynchronous** so you need to pass the `this.handleUpload` function as a callback in order to updload the files once `setState` is completed.

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) :

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

```
onFilesAdded = files => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        files: [...prevState.files, ...files]
    }), this.handleUpdload)
}
```